# Java Desktop application with derby database embedded schemas not found error

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

I have a issue. I want to create a java application that I will deploy to an other PC with a derby embedded database. When I run the application in netbeans it works fine!!!!! I connect to db; I can insert data with no problem. However after generating an exe by Jar2exe it shows me an error such that schema doesn't exist, as you can see in the screenshot !!!!! I am new in derby and it is my first application.

```html
package cd.espoir.GestionCarburantVodacom;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Espoir M
 */
public class ConnectToDb{
//creationBDDerby.sql
   

  
    public static Connection Connect() {
//        String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:Vodacom";
//        Properties properties = new Properties();
//        properties.put("create", "true");
//        properties.put("user", "vodacom");
//        properties.put("password", "vodacom");
        Connection con = null;
        String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;create=true;user=app;password=app";
        try {

   // Configures and loads Database
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:VODACOM;create=true", "vodacom" ,"vodacom");


            System.out.println("chargement recu");

        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException| IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectToDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return con;
    }
//    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException {
//         InputStream sqlRequest = new FileInputStream(new File("creationBDDerby.sql"));
//        Connection Connect = Connect();
//        Statement st = Connect.createStatement();
//   
//               importSQL(Connect, sqlRequest);
//        System.out.println("executio parfaitemen ok");
//    }
//    public static void importSQL(Connection conn, InputStream in) throws SQLException
//{ /** la methode execute une requete sql depuis iun fichier sql en pararamtre **/
// Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
// s.useDelimiter("(;(\r)?\n)|(--\n)");
// Statement st = null;
// try
// {
//  st = conn.createStatement();
//  while (s.hasNext())
//  {
//   String line = s.next();
//   if (line.startsWith("/*!") && line.endsWith("*/"))
//   {
//    int i = line.indexOf(' ');
//    line = line.substring(i + 1, line.length() - " */".length());
//   }
//
//   if (line.trim().length() > 0)
//   {
//    st.execute(line);
//   }
//  }
// }
// finally
// {
//  if (st != null) st.close();
// }
//}
 public boolean Verifier() {
        if (jTextField_Nom.getText().isEmpty() || jTextField_Nom.getText() == "") {
         
            jTextPane1_succesfull.setText("Veuillez saisir le nom");
               jTextPane1_succesfull.setForeground(Color.red);
            return true;
        } else {
            Connection cnx = ConnectToDb.Connect();
            try {

                String request = "SELECT Nom FROM Utilisateur where Nom='" + jTextField_Nom.getText() + "'";
                PreparedStatement ps = cnx.prepareStatement(request);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                 
                    jTextPane1_succesfull.setText("cet Agent  est deja enregistre");
                       jTextPane1_succesfull.setForeground(Color.red);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);

            }
        }

        return false;

    }
// the comment code was use to create tables in database 

    enter code here

    public void AddUser() {
        Verifier();
        if (!Verifier()) {
            try {
                Connection cnx = ConnectToDb.Connect();
                PreparedStatement ps = cnx.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Utilisateur (Nom, Service, Fonction) \n"
                        + " VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
                ps.setString(1, jTextField_Nom.getText());
                ps.setString(2, (String) jComboBox_Service.getSelectedItem());
                ps.setString(3, (String) jComboBox_Fonction.getSelectedItem());
                ps.executeUpdate();
                cnx.close();
                ps.close();
               
                jTextPane1_succesfull.setText("Agent  ajouter avec suceess");
                     jTextPane1_succesfull.setForeground(Color.green);
                jButton_Valider.setEnabled(false);
                jTextField_Nom.setText(" ");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);

            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: https://plus.google.com/113497765187161548343/posts/G8DgJ14UyeL?hl=en&utm_source=lmnavbr&utm_medium=embd&utm_campaign=lrnmre&rtsl=0&pid=6127500064787510114&oid=113497765187161548343

Comment: https://plus.google.com/113497765187161548343/posts/G8DgJ14UyeL?hl=en&utm_source=lmnavbr&utm_medium=embd&utm_campaign=lrnmre&rtsl=0&pid=6127500052213959874&oid=113497765187161548343

Comment: the first and the second are there

Comment: Some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038840/exception-using-liquibase-from-java-with-derby-embedded/12048102#12048102